# "Sparse" k-Colourings of Graphs

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Is there a 4-chromatic graph $G$ and a 4-colouring $c$ of $G$ such that for every vertex $v$, the closed neighborhood $N[v] = \{v\} \cup \{ u\ |\ (v,u) \in G \}$ has at most three colours?

Answer (score 1):

There exist graphs with arbitrarily large chromatic number with colorings so that each vertex and its neighbors are colored in at most 3 colors. See [this reference](http://www.math.illinois.edu/~z-furedi/PUBS/erdos_furedi_hajnal_komjath_rodl_seress.pdf). It would be interesting to know what the smallest such examples are though.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same person as the original poster, thanks for the reference!

A friend offline pointed out that you can always decrease the number of total colors in such a coloring by choosing the largest color (say, 4) and replacing it with the smallest color not in the neighborhood of each vertex with that color. So the answer to my original question is no, as the chromatic number of such a graph is actually less than 4. I do agree, the question about what smallest examples look like is an interesting one (the bounds in the paper are frightfully large).

Comment: I don't think it's that easy. How do you know the colouring is still proper? E.g., if you are changing vertex $w$ from blue to green, how do you know $w$ isn't already adjacent to a green vertex?

Comment: Fix a colour class and suppose $w$ has that colour. By assumption, the neighborhood of $w$ (including $w$) has at most three colours, so there must be a colour not appearing in that neighborhood. Change $w$ to that colour --- since it doesn't appear, you are guaranteed that all the local constraints are still satisfied. Repeat until all vertices in that colour class are changed.

Since no two vertices in the same colour class are next to each other, you are guaranteed that repeatedly applying this local operation will not cause conflicts.

Comment: @Robere You seem to be correct, but I can't figure out how that can be consistent with the reference I provided. If a graph is colored in $n\geq 4$ colors so that there are at most 3 colors in the closed neighborhood of any vertex, then take one color class and recolor each vertex to a color that does not appear in the closed neighborhood of that vertex to obtain a proper $(n-1)$-coloring with only 3 colors in the closed neighborhood of any vertex. Inductively applying this seems to prove such a graph is 3-colorable, in contradiction to the reference provided. I must be missing something...

Comment: @Robere Ignore that. the new coloring wouldn't have the property that only 3 colors are used in the neighborhood of any vertex. So while you can't have a 4-coloring of a 4-chromatic graph with only 3 colors in the closed neighborhood of a vertex, you could potentially have such a 5-coloring.

Comment: Yes, it seems really odd! I think that if you have strictly greater than 4 colours, then by applying this local swap argument you can actually increase the number of colours in a neighborhood of a vertex. So you could have a (5, 3)-colouring that is transformed into a (4,4)-colouring, for example (using the language in the reference).

Comment: @PerryElliott-Iverson I think we had the same thought at the same time.